# svn diff for a complete file?

Tags: svn, diff

**Given:** an SVN repository, a `bin` directory inside it and a `script.pl` inside this `bin`. Some revisions ago, `bin` and `script.pl` has been added to the repository in one commit. Since then, some revisions has been applied to `script.pl`.

**Needed:** a diff command which would return a complete diff for `script.pl` from zero to HEAD, i.e. a diff with all lines added.

**Background:** this diff is needed for code review, for feeding to [ReviewBoard](http://www.review-board.org)

**Problem:** `svn diff` with `-r X:HEAD` (`X` being the first revision of `script.pl`) produces a diff between the first version and HEAD while `-r X-1:HEAD` tell me the file `script.pl` is unknown in the revision `X-1`, which is actually correct. However, I can't find a proper solution which would include the diff from an empty file. I also can't diff the `bin` directory, since it has been added in the same commit as `script.pl`

**Solution:** **?**

Comment: Must be a single 'svn diff' command, or can you script around it?

Comment: Would "svn blame" be something you're looking for? That'll show you when that exact line was added to the file.

Answer (score 6):

Without temp file:

```
echo "" | diff -u - script.pl
```

Comment: why not use `/dev/null`? with `diff -u /dev/null script.pl`?

Comment: SVN substitution keywords (e.g. $Date$, $Revision$, $Id$, etc.) will be expanded in the working copy, whereas "svn diff" doesn't expand these keywords, so this is not the same

Answer (score 2):

Some versions of SVN seems to let you do `svn diff -r 0:HEAD file.txt`, but some don't. For those that don't, use the following:

```
svn diff --old=/path/to/root/of/repo@1 --new=/path/to/file.txt
```

Both of these work for any folder/file/files!

Answer (score 1):

This is the hack I use in this situation:

```
cp file1 file2
svn add file2
svn diff file2 > file1.diff
svn rm --force file2
```

Answer (score 0):

Wait, you want a diff between the current (HEAD) version of script.pl and the empty file? You don't need a *diff* for that, because the diff would just be all the lines of the current script.pl with plusses in front of them. Exciting, no?

If you really need it in *diff* form, Why not just do this?

```
$ touch EMPTYFILE  # creates a new, empty file
$ diff -u EMPTYFILE script.pl > script.pl.diff
```

... or the local equivalent, should you be stuck with a less capable system.

Comment: Let's put it this way: touching and diffing is a hack. Doing this stuff with Subversion pure was the actual intention of the question -- especially because I'd like to use ReviewBoard which makes diffs itself using Subversion. I wondered why Subversion is unable to produce a proper diff and assumed I'm dumb, but it turns out it's Subversion and not me who is a bit under-featured :)

But thanks anyway, I might be able to hack something together.

Comment: Also, another problem with this is that the SVN substitution keywords (e.g. $Date$, $Revision$, $Id$, etc.) will be expanded in the working copy, which you don't want in a diff. "svn diff" doesn't expand these keywords, and that is the behavior you want.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and also didn't find a solution.

The workaround was to produce diff of a couple of recent revisions of the file, then "Expand changes" shows you the complete file and allows to comment anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Subversion will not do exactly what you want. The best you can do is a diff of the lowest level directory that existed when `bin/script.pl` was committed (presumably, `bin`'s parent).

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat a hack but should get you going...

Commit everything

```
for file in find . -name "*.*" | grep -v .svn; do echo "" > $file; done
svn diff | sed -e 's/^-/+/g' > diffs.txt
```

`rm -rf` that directory and `svn up` it back.

Answer (score -3):

From the top of my head:

```
svn diff -r X-1:HEAD FILENAME@X
```

The filename isn't a unique key over time, but filename@revision is.

Comment: Looked promising, but sadly: 

    svn: Unable to find repository location for `script.pl` in revision X-1